# How do you query property values with SQL Server JSON without knowing the parent object keys?

Tags: json, sql-server

Given the following JSON in SQL Server, how do you get the "Foo" values without knowing the parent keys ("John" and "Jane")?

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = '{
    "John" : {
        "favoriteMovie": "Star Wars",
        "Foo": 42
    },
    "Jane" : {
        "favoriteMovie": "Caddyshack",
        "Foo": 66
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2016 or later, you can use [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql) and [`APPLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql) for the number of levels in your hierarchy.

```
select b.[key], b.[value]
from openjson(@json) a
    cross apply openjson(a.[value]) b
where b.[key] like N'Foo';
```

Results:

```
key value
Foo 42
Foo 66
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way is to use `XML` node method to get the desired result. However, the method is odd but it would helps

```
select 
          ltrim(replace(replace(a.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), char(10), ''), '}', '')) json from
(
    select cast('<m>'+replace(@json, ',', '</m><m>')+'</m>' as xml) as json
)a cross apply json.nodes ('/m') as json(a) 
where a.value('.', 'varchar(max)') like '%foo%'
```

Result :

```
json
"Foo": 42    
"Foo": 66
```